# Creating a function to reverse order a hex value as string

Tags: delphi, pascal, endianness, mifare

how to put this...

I have been struggling all day to reverse the UID value of an Mifare NFC card, the value i read as a hex string, which i can convert to a integer, this works very well with a 4 bytes UID.

Things gets messy when it comes to a mifare desfire card which can have a large UID  example :

04 44 44 22 E0 62 80

The value is read correctly and i can even convert this to a decimal using my functions StrToInt('$' + TheUIDvalue)

now the weird part is that i need to reverse this using the following function:

```
function HexToInt(s: string): Longword;
var
  b: byte;
  c: Char;
begin
  Result := 0;
  s := UpperCase(s);
  for b := 1 to Length(s) do
  begin
    Result := Result * 16;
    c := s[b];
    case c of
      '0' .. '9':
        Inc(Result, Ord(c) - Ord('0'));
      'A' .. 'F':
        Inc(Result, Ord(c) - Ord('A') + 10);
    else
      begin
        Result := 0
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

function LongEndian(L : UInt64) : UInt64;
begin
  result := ((L and $000000FF) shl 24) or
            ((L and $0000FF00) shl 8) or
            ((L and $00FF0000) shr 8) or
            ((L and $FF000000) shr 24);
end;

function TfrmMain.HexResponseReversed ( input: string): string;
begin
  result := IntToHex(EndianLong(hexToInt(input)));
end;



The result i get is : 
         80 62 E0 22
04 44 44 22 E0 62 80
```

So there is something seriously missing here... please excuse the messy code

I suspect there is something wrong with the IntToHex function

Comment: LongWord is also a platform dependent type and in general should be avoided.  The HexToInt function above outputs 8 bytes on 64 bit POSIX platforms like Linux or 64bit iOS but only 4 bytes on everything else including 64 bit Windows.

Comment: I actually tried to find out how to do this with a nested loop, but seems i could not find a good way to do it, as of yet

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for sharing your insights, altho i must admit i found some of these codes on the web, this longendian function was the best i could find, but bit shifting have never been my thing, i would appreciate if you could send me in the right direction on how to make that function work with the whole 8 byte.  i corrected the longword, but still the longendian function is messing it up

Comment: @Plastkort I posted an answer now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `HexToInt()` function returns a `LongWord`, so its output is dependant on the platform.  For 64bit POSIX platforms like Linux and iOS, it is 8 bytes, for other platforms it is 4 bytes.

Also, your `LongEndian()` function only swaps 4 bytes despite operating on an 8-byte `UInt64`.

So, you should either:

- fix those functions to operate on the full 8 bytes on all platforms, eg:

  ```pascal
  function HexToInt64(s: string): UInt64;
  var
    Len, I: Integer;
    c: Char;
  begin
    Result := 0;
    Len := Length(s);
    if Len = 0 then Exit;
    if Odd(Len) then
    begin
      s := '0' + s;
      Inc(Len);
    end;
    if Len > 16 then Exit;
    for I := 1 to Len do
    begin
      Result := Result * 16;
      c := s[I];
      case c of
        '0' .. '9':
          Inc(Result, Ord(c) - Ord('0'));
        'A' .. 'F':
          Inc(Result, Ord(c) - Ord('A') + 10);
        'a' .. 'f':
          Inc(Result, Ord(c) - Ord('a') + 10);
      else
        begin
          Result := 0;
          Exit;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  function EndianLong(L : UInt64) : UInt64;
  begin
    Result := ((L and $00000000000000FF) shl 56) or
              ((L and $000000000000FF00) shl 40) or
              ((L and $0000000000FF0000) shl 24) or
              ((L and $00000000FF000000) shl 8) or
              ((L and $000000FF00000000) shr 8) or
              ((L and $0000FF0000000000) shr 24) or
              ((L and $00FF000000000000) shr 40) or
              ((L and $FF00000000000000) shr 56);
  end;

  function TfrmMain.HexResponseReversed(input: string): string;
  begin
    Result := IntToHex(EndianLong(HexToInt64(input)));
  end;
  ```
- decode the individual `HH` pairs of the hex string into a byte array, then swap the order of the array elements, and then create a new hex string from the array elements:

  ```pascal
  uses
    ..., Classes;

  function HexToBytes(s: string): TBytes;
  var
    Len: Integer;
  begin
    Result := nil;
    Len := Length(s);
    if Len = 0 then Exit;
    if Odd(Len) then
    begin
      s := '0' + s;
      Inc(Len);
    end;
    Len := Len div 2;
    SetLength(Result, Len);
    if HexToBin(PChar(s), PAnsiChar(PByte(Result)), Len) <> Len then
      SetLength(Result, 0);
  end;

  function BytesToHex(Bytes: TBytes): string;
  var
    Len: Integer;
  begin
    Result := nil;
    Len := Length(Bytes);
    if Len = 0 then Exit;
    SetLength(Result, Len * 2);
    BinToHex(PAnsiChar(PByte(Bytes)), PChar(Result), Len);
  end;

  function EndianLong(Bytes : TBytes) : TBytes;
  var
    Len, I, J: Integer;
    B: Byte;
  begin
    Result := nil;
    Len := Length(Bytes); 
    if Len = 0 then Exit;
    Result := Copy(Bytes, 0, Len);
    if Len = 1 then Exit;
    J := Pred(Len);
    for I := 0 to Pred(Len div 2) do
    begin
      B := Result[I];
      Result[I] := Result[J];
      Result[J] := B;
      Dec(J);
    end;
  end;

  function TfrmMain.HexResponseReversed(input: string): string;
  begin
    Result := BytesToHex(EndianLong(HexToBytes(input)));
  end;
  ```

That being said, a 3rd option would be to simply swap the `HH` pairs of the input string directly, without converting the whole input string to an integer or byte array at all:

```pascal
uses
  ..., SysUtils;

function TfrmMain.HexResponseReversed(input: string): string;
const
  HexDigits = ['0'..'9', 'A'..'F', 'a'..'f'];
var
  Len, I: Integer;
  P, Q: PChar;
  Hex: array[0..1] of Char;
begin
  Result := '';
  Len := Length(input);
  if Len = 0 then Exit;
  Result := input;
  if Odd(Len) then
  begin
    Result := '0' + Result;
    Inc(Len);
  end;
  Len := Len div 2;
  if Len = 1 then Exit;
  UniqueString(Result);
  P := PChar(Result);
  Q := AnsiLastChar(Result);
  Dec(Q);
  For I := 1 to Len div 2 do
  begin
    Move(P^, Hex, SizeOf(Hex));
    if not ((Hex[0] in HexDigits) and (Hex[1] in HexDigits)) then
    begin
      Result := '';
      Exit;
    end;
    Move(Q^, P^, SizeOf(Hex));
    Move(Hex, Q^, SizeOf(Hex));
    Inc(P, 2);
    Dec(Q, 2);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I will take a look in a few hours :-)

Comment: I really like the last one you had here, ,but it seems something is not right

I input 04646EAAE7380, Output was : 804646EAAE7300 Expected result : 03EE7A6E6404

Comment: @Plastkort "*I input 04646EAAE7380, Output was : 804646EAAE7300*" - my bad, the loop had a logic bug that ended up swapping the same `HH` pairs twice, effectively undoing the swapping. I fixed it. "*Expected result : 03EE7A6E6404*" - why would you expect `HH` pairs that are not in the input?

Comment: thats amazing, looks like it working, i have been spinning around my head to get around this.. your first solution seem to work as well, but it seems it adds trailing zeros if the hexvalue is less than 7 bytes for some reason

Comment: @Plastkort "*your first solution ... seems it adds trailing zeros if the hexvalue is less than 7 bytes*" - yes, because that is just how integers work. Unused high bits are set to 0, which then get swapped into the lower bits, and `IntToHex()` ignores leading high 0 bits but not trailing low 0 bits. If you want that, you will have to truncate the result of `IntToHex()` manually

Comment: @Plastkort "*The second solution i was unable to get working*" - which step is failing?

Comment: yeah i truncated the trailing zeros, worked like a charm. the seconds solution worked after second test, seems there was a unit that conflicted with the TBytes

Comment: Or just copy from https://github.com/graemeg/freepascal/blob/master/rtl/objpas/sysutils/sysstr.inc